# How to make folium multiple markers's popups display simultaneously on click on any one of them?

Tags: python, leaflet, pandas, folium

this code works fine but it only displays the popup of the clicked marker. I rather want that all markers' popups display when clicking on any marker of them.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

data = {'Latitude': [41.5, 42.5, 43.5],
        'Longitude': [0.1, -0.1, 0.0],
        'Name': ['Marker 1', 'Marker 2', 'Marker 3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

m = folium.Map(location=[42.5, 0.0], zoom_start=6)


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']], popup=row['Name']).add_to(m)

m.save("map.html")
```